# Is there any bonus to a second Plague knife on Plague Marines?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I'm new to 8th edition 40k and as far as I understand you no longer receive the extra attack for 2 melee weapons. But the Death Guard codex gives the option: 
"Any Plague Marine can replace their boltgun with either a bubotic axe or a second plague knife."

Is there any bonus to taking a second plague knife or a second identical melee weapon in 8th Edition?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look for the **Vectors of Death and Disease** special rule which suggests that amongst it's other effects, having two plague knives increases the bearer's attacks characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

@aslum is correct, having a second plague knife (or a bubotic axe) increases the models attacks by one. As I understand it this extra attack can be made with any weapon the model has (i.e. if you wanted to you could use the extra attack from the axe as a knife attack).

I think that taking extra melee weapons has no benefit RE number of attacks unless it says so in the data sheet or weapon rules. It does allow you to a choice of weapon to use. For example a model with a power fist and a close combat weapon might not want the -1 to hit when fighting a horde of poorly armoured enemies.